# Turtle - Not Touching Color

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm making a game in Turtle's graphics. Here's the code

```
import turtle
import time

width = -462
height = 387

cellHeight = 387

turtle.title('Tutorial Game')

##TurtleImage
turtle.addshape('cell1.gif')
turtle.addshape('platformTile.gif')

##Render
def renderScreen():
    #Background
    turtle.bgcolor('green')
    ##Roof
    for i in range(3):
        roof()
        global cellHeight
        cellHeight -= 32
    ##Floor
    cellHeight = -387
    for i in range(2):
        floor()
        global cellHeight
        cellHeight += 32
    char()

def roof():
    turtle.shape('platformTile.gif')
    turtle.goto(width, cellHeight)
    for i in range(30):
        turtle.stamp()
        turtle.forward(32)

def floor():
    turtle.shape('platformTile.gif')
    turtle.goto(width, cellHeight)
    for i in range(30):
        turtle.stamp()
        turtle.forward(32)

def char():
    turtle.shape('cell1.gif')
    turtle.showturtle()
    turtle.goto(0, 0)
    turtle.onkey(forward, 'd')
    turtle.onkey(backward, 'a')
    turtle.onkey(up, 'space')
    turtle.listen()

##Movement

def forward():
    turtle.forward(32)

def backward():
    turtle.backward(32)

def jump():
    turtle.setheading(90)
    turtle.forward(32)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    turtle.forward(32)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    turtle.setheading(270)
    turtle.forward(32)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    turtle.forward(32)
    turtle.setheading(0)

def up():
    turtle.setheading(90)
    turtle.forward(32)
    turtle.setheading(0)

turtle.penup()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.speed(0)

renderScreen()


 turtle.done()
```

I want to make it so that when the character isn't touching the yellow tiles, it floats down until it is touching the yellow tiles. I'm thinking, maybe, if it isn't touching the dark yellow color

Any help?

[image: Example of what I want to happen]

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the character goes below a specific degree in the y-axis (for example 10); where its y-axis decreases if it is higher than that, and it will stop (use break in that loop/if statement) if it reaches that limit (the 10)

Answer (score 0):

Below is my rework of your code that attempts to simplify it, add the downward motion, and get it to test the floor boundary:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

CELL_SIZE = 32
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 30 * CELL_SIZE, 24 * CELL_SIZE  # screen size in cell units

PLATFORM_HEIGHT = 2 * CELL_SIZE  # height of platform
LIMIT = PLATFORM_HEIGHT - HEIGHT / 2

STAMP_UNIT = 20  # turtle's default cursor size

def renderPlatform():
    """ Go to the bottom of the screen and stamp the platform """

    turtle = Turtle('square', visible=False)
    turtle.speed('fastest')
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(0, PLATFORM_HEIGHT / 2 - HEIGHT / 2)
    turtle.setheading(90)
    turtle.shapesize(WIDTH / STAMP_UNIT, PLATFORM_HEIGHT / STAMP_UNIT)
    turtle.color('yellow')
    turtle.stamp()

def forward():
    character.forward(CELL_SIZE)

def backward():
    character.backward(CELL_SIZE)

def up():
    character.sety(character.ycor() + CELL_SIZE)

def down():
    character.sety(character.ycor() - CELL_SIZE)

    if character.ycor() - CELL_SIZE / 2 <= LIMIT:  # test for collision with platform
        character.stamp()  # leave a marker
        character.hideturtle()
        character.goto(0, CELL_SIZE / 2)  # start anew floating downward
        character.showturtle()

    screen.ontimer(down, 1000)  # move character downward once a second

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
screen.title('Tutorial Game')
screen.bgcolor('green')

renderPlatform()

character = Turtle('square')
character.shapesize(CELL_SIZE / STAMP_UNIT)
character.penup()
character.color('red')
character.sety(CELL_SIZE / 2)  # might want to start higher in actual game

screen.onkey(forward, 'd')
screen.onkey(backward, 'a')
screen.onkey(up, 'space')

screen.listen()

screen.ontimer(down, 1000)  # start character falling

screen.mainloop()
```

Hopefully you can use some of this logic in your solution.

[image]

You'll need to modify your `up()` logic to limit the movement to the top of the stage.  Ditto `forward()` and `backward()` with respect to the sides.